# torch/nn: What's the canonical way to multiply by a constant matrix?

Tags: torch

`nn.MM` requires a table argument of the matrices that will be multiplied. In my case, one of the matrices is the output of some previously defined model (e.g. an `nn.Sequential`) and the other is just a constant matrix.  How can I inject a constant into `nn`'s pipeline and should I be worried that optimizer will start changing it if I do?

I'm aware that I could solve the injection problem by:

1. Writing my own `nn.Module`. This seems heavy handed.
2. Breaking the model into two parts and manually injecting the constant. I really want the model to just be some `nn.Module` subclass that gets called with `:forward(input)` and allows consumers to be blissfully ignorant of the existence of the constant.
3. Using `nn.ParallelTable`, but that would also expose the constant to model consumers.
4. Using `nn.Linear` with no bias and overwriting the weights. I'm just not sure how to prevent the optimizer from performing the update.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create an nn.Linear and the override the :accGradParameters to be a no-op function

```
m = nn.Linear(100,200)
-- copy your weights / bias into m.weight / m.bias
m.accGradParameters = function() end
-- m is a constant multiplier thing
```

Comment: It's somewhat surprising that monkey patching this even works with `torch.save` and `torch.load`. I'll take it.

Answer (score -1):

Use [MulConstant](https://github.com/torch/nn/blob/master/doc/transfer.md#mulconstant)

```
m=nn.MulConstant(7,true)(myMatrix)
```